# Conditional type hints in python

Tags: python, type-hinting

How to do proper type hinting in Python when certain packages only declare type hints when `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` is enabled?

For example, in flask:

```
# This works in mypy, not in python
# because flask checks for t.TYPE_CHECKING
# before declaring WSGIEnvironment

from flask import WSGIEnvironment
environ: WSGIEnvironment
```

What is the usual or clean way to solve this?
Do I need to redeclare the type declarations present in the typeshed?

Comment: `WSGIEnvironment` doesn't appear to be defined by `flask` at all; it's a type alias that comes from `mypy` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Just test for  `t.TYPE_CHECKING`  in the same way in your code (put the import statement inside the `if` guard. there is no effect of said annotations in "Python", as you put it - just at static type checking time.

```
import flask
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
     environ: flask.WSGIEnvironment

...
```

If you want to annotate things like function definitions, I think the only workaround is to create a dummy WSGIEnvironment, with the same test:

```
import flask
import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from flask import WSGIEnvironment
else:
    WSGIEnvironment = t.Any
```

In this case the otherwise unrecomended any will never be used during type-checking, and will just supply a value to be used during runtime.

Comment: What if it's not a global variable and eg. a function parameter?

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been solved in version 3.11 by the addition of the [`wsgiref.types` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.types), adding the following types:

```
class wsgiref.types.StartResponse
A typing.Protocol describing start_response() callables (PEP 3333).

wsgiref.types.WSGIEnvironment
A type alias describing a WSGI environment dictionary.

wsgiref.types.WSGIApplication
A type alias describing a WSGI application callable.

class wsgiref.types.InputStream
A typing.Protocol describing a WSGI Input Stream.

class wsgiref.types.ErrorStream
A typing.Protocol describing a WSGI Error Stream.

class wsgiref.types.FileWrapper
A typing.Protocol describing a file wrapper. See wsgiref.util.FileWrapper for a concrete implementation of this protocol.
```